# What event does jQuery fire when using append on a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, append, textarea

I'm trying to monitor for any changes in a textarea:

```
<textarea id="log-box__data"></textarea>
```

Changes are made to the textarea **exclusively** via jQuery `append`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myBtn', function(e) {
  $('#log-box__data').append('someText' + '\n');
});
```

What event is fired whenever something is `append`[ed] to the textarea?

And, if there isn't one, how can I monitor for this change?

**Things I've Tried:**

```
$(document).on('input change keyup paste', '#log-box__data', function() {
  alert( "foobar" );
});
```

None of those events fire when `#myBtn` is clicked.

Comment: why uses , append() instead val()?

Comment: you should use val() instead of append()

Comment: `append` also works as a matter of fact...

Comment: Why not just add `.trigger("change")` after the append

Comment: @Rahul Naik - Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using trigger function after append will help

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myBtn', function(e) {
  
  $('#log-box__data').append('someText' + '\n');
  $('#log-box__data').trigger("change");
  
});

$('#log-box__data').on('change', function(e) {
  alert( "foobar" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="log-box__data"></textarea><br />
<button id="myBtn">add text</button>
```

Comment: Yup, that'll do it. I never thought to trigger the event manually. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

append is not a good idea and also set a value will never call the onchange event so try below code to trigger manually

```
 $("#myBtn").bind("click",function(){
     $("#log-box__data").val("yourtexthere").trigger('change');
 });
```